# Firebase Service Account for Firestore and Remote Config

Tags: firebase, google-apps-script, google-cloud-firestore, google-oauth, service-accounts

I have created/forked a lil Google Apps Script Library to manage Firebase Firestore and Firebase Remote Config called [FirebaseGoogleAppsScript](https://github.com/kferrone/FirebaseGoogleAppsScript). The goal is to simply manage the contents of your collections in an apps script as well as update your remote config.

My issue is I can't get the a service account to do both.

Firebase creates two service accounts upon creating a project:

1. The first is listed in the Firebase Console -> Project Settings -> Service Accounts. This one I use within my cloud functions to retrieve the Remote Config just fine. However in the Apps Script Project it is unable to retrieve any data from firestore. I tried adding all kinds of roles including `Owner` and `Editor` yet no firestore data, but I still can get the RemoteConfig.
2. The second is only visible in the GCP service accounts and has the title: `Firebase Admin SDK Service Agent` with the roles `Firebase Admin SDK Administrator Service Agent` and `Service Account Token Creator`. This one is able to retrieve all the data from firestore within an Apps Script Project. However in the apps script project I can't get it to retrieve the RemoteConfig even if I add the role `Firebase Remote Config Admin`.

I have also made my own service account which was able to get the Remote config and just about everything else from Firebase except the Firestore data. Seems only the one service account created by Firebase is able to get any data.

To recreate the issue simply deploy my lil [FirebaseGoogleAppsScript](https://github.com/kferrone/FirebaseGoogleAppsScript) project and associate it to the same GCP project Firebase is connected to. There is a test file in it which can recreate the issue assuming you have some data in RemoteConfig and a collection called `posts` with some docs.

What the heck is going on here? Why can't I make a service account who can access Firestore and RemoteConfig? Any ideas on what to do to create a proper role to do both? Do I really have to use two separate service accounts?

Comment: Here is an alternative (albeit more difficult) approach. You can skip using service accounts altogether by associating your apps script with the GCP project, setting the requisite scopes in the manifest file (appscript.json) and then calling the respective REST APIs directly via `UrlFetchApp.fetch()`. You'll need to pass your Apps Script project's access token (use `ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()` to retrieve it) as an authorization header in all your calls to `UrlFetchApp.fetch()`. You'll need to familiarize yourself with the API's endpoints and resource payloads (typically JSON formatted).

Comment: I tried this. It failed on the OAuth consent screen. I added the scopes to the application.json and the OAuth consent screen. My app isn't verified therefore it gave a warning that sensitive resource scopes like the ones I asked for are not activate till verified. I think I'm stuck with using more than one service account.